# fb app - invite friend to this app button

Tags: facebook

I develop small fb app (which will be available on separate domain and through app.facebook.com as well) and I would like to incorporate something like "Invite my friends to this app" button (don't know exact name for this so I used quotes). How can I do this? I am using fb php sdk and don't want to use fbml becuase as I saw it is depreciated. MANY THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript) to open the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

With this dialog the user can select friends to which the requests will be sent.
It's very easy, and the (basic) code should look something like this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
        status: true,
        cookie: true
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function invite() {
    FB.ui({
        method: "apprequests",
        message: "Check out my great app"
    }, inviteCallback);
}

function inviteCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: thanks! that's exactly what I was looking for. :) unfortunately left and right fb black borders around this popup widnow are blank (top and bottom margins are presented only)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, any change you can post a screen capture?

Comment: please check this image http://postimage.org/image/q2qsez5ap/ (left and right black alpha opacity border is missing)

Comment: Weird. Is this inside a canvas app or on a website? You have a link that I can check myself?

Comment: unfortunately it is on my localhost. but this happens on blank page (blank html) only. I have implemented the same code to another page and it works ok. thank you very much for your help!